# Python dictionary keys(which are class objects) comparison with multiple comparer

Tags: python, hash, dictionary

I am using custom objects as keys in python dictionary. These objects has some default *hash* and *eq* methods defined which are being used in default comparison 
But in some function i need to use a different way to compare these objects.
So is there any way to override or pass a new comparer for these key comparison for this specific function only.

Updated: My class has following type of functionality ( here i can not edit **hash** method ,it will affect a lot at other places)

```
class test(object):

    def __init__(self,name,city):
        self.name=name
        self.city=city

    def __eq__(self,other):
        hash_equality= (self.name==other.name)
        if(not hash_equality):
            #check with lower
            return (self.name.lower()==other.name.lower())


    def  __hash__(self):
        return self.name.__hash__()

my_dict={}
a=test("a","city1")
my_dict[a]="obj1"
b=test("a","city2")
print b in my_dict  #prints true
c=test("A","city1")
print c in my_dict  #prints false
print c in my_dict.keys() #prints true
# my_dict[c]   throw error
```

This is the normal functionality. But in one specific method i want to override/or pass a new custom comparer where the new **hash** code is like

```
def  __hash__(self):
    return self.name.lower().__hash__()
```

so that `c in my_dict` returns ture

or `my_dict[c] will return "obj1"`

Sorry for so many updates.

Like in sorting we can pass custom method as comparer , is there any way to do the same here.

Comment: I misread the question (thought is was about sorting). Still, can you provide some code to illustrate what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: i need one specific comparer method in one function only.And by sorting way , i mean to say that as in sort we can pass comparer ,can that be done while checking the keys

Comment: By the way, are you sure that you want your `__eq__`-function to compare hashes? Hashes can have collisions, so you might get unexpected behavior in some cases.

Comment: i think i was clear in the question earlier . updated the code part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now I am using custom dict(derived class of dict) which take comparer as parameter and i have overridden the **contains** and **getitems**() which checks and give value based on the comparer.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to make this work is to create a copy of your dictionary using the new hash and comparison-function. The reason is that the dictionary needs to rehash every stored key with the new hash-function to make the lookup work as you desire. Since you cannot provide a custom hash-function to a dictionary (it always uses the one of the key-objects), your best bet is probably to wrap your objects in a type that uses your custom hash and comparison-functions.

```
class WrapKey(object):
    __init__(self, wrapee):
        self._wrapee = wrapee

    __hash__(self):
        return self._wrapee.name.lower().__hash__()

    __eq__(self, other):
        return self._wrapee.name == other._wrapee.name


def func(d):
    d_copy = dict((WrapKey(key), value) for key, value in d.iteritems())
    # d_copy will now ignore case
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [comparison methods](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) you can define in an object.

Depending on what you want to do, [`__cmp__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__) might also be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

A little hack for this situation:

```
class test(object):

    def __init__(self,name,city,hash_func=None):
        self.name=name
        self.city=city
        self.hash_func = hash_func

    def __eq__(self,other):
        return self.__hash__()==other.__hash__()

    def  __hash__(self):
        if self.hash_func is None:
            return self.name.__hash__()
        else:
            return self.hash_func(self)

my_dict={}
a=test("a","city1")
my_dict[a]="obj1"
b=test("a","city2")
print b in my_dict  #prints true
c=test("A","city1")
print c in my_dict  #Prints false
c.hash_func = lambda x: x.name.lower().__hash__()
print c in my_dict #Now it prints true
```

You can't change the hash stored in the dict, but you can change the hash use for looking up. Of course, this leads to something weird like this

```
my_dict={}
a=test("a","city1")
my_dict[a]="obj1"
a.hash_func = lambda x: 1
for key in my_dict:
    print key in my_dict # False
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps : Implement a custom key class and override hash and equality function.

e.g.

```
class CustomDictKey(object):

def __init__(self, 
             param1,
             param2):

            self._param1 = param1
            self._param2 = param2

 # overriding hash and equality function does the trick

def __hash__(self):
    return hash((self._param1,
             self._param2))

def __eq__(self, other):
    return ( ( self._param1,
             self._param2 ) == ( other._param1,
             other._param2) )

def __str__(self):
    return "param 1: {0} param 2: {1}  ".format(self._param1, self._param2)
```

## main method

```
if name == 'main':

    # create custom key
    k1  = CustomDictKey(10,5)

    k2  = CustomDictKey (2, 4)

    dictionary = {}

    #insert elements in dictionary with custom key
    dictionary[k1] = 10
    dictionary[k2] = 20

    # access dictionary values with custom keys and print values
    print "key: ", k1, "val :", dictionary[k1]
    print "key: ", k2, "val :", dictionary[k2]
```

Refer the link  [Using custom class as key in Python dictionary](http://assortedtechnotes.blogspot.in/2015/05/how-to-use-custom-type-as-dictionary.html)  for complete details.