# Updating an ordered list of dicts from a new list of dicts (priority merge)

Tags: python, algorithm, merge

I'm currently faced with having to semi-regularly update (synchronize) a large-ish list of dicts from a canonical changing source while maintaining my own updates to it. A non-standard merge, for which the simplest description is probably:-

- `A` is my own list of dicts (updated by my program to include cached values as additional keys.
- `b` is some regularly sent information from a source (A was originally identical to b). It contains a few keys, but not the cached values I've added to A.
- `keys = ['key1', 'key2']` is a list of keys which both A and b have (A has more keys than that.
- `mkey = 'mtime'` is a special key which both A and b have which indicates that I should invalidate the cached values of A.

Basically, if a dict in `A` matches a dict in `b`, I should keep the dict in A unless `b['mtime'] > A['mtime']`. If a dict appears in `A` but not in `b` I get rid of it, while if it appears in `b` but not in `A` I add it to `A`.

My holy grail objective is to not lose any cached key-value pairs in `A` at all, but I'm having trouble achieving that. My current solution looks something like this:-

```
def priority_merge(A, b, keys, mkey):
    retval = []
    b_index = 0
    for elemA in A:
        if b_index >= len(b):
            break  # No more items in b
        elemb = b[b_index]
        minA = { k: elemA[k] for k in keys }
        minb = { k: elemb[k] for k in keys }
        if minA == minb:  # Found a match
            if elemA[mkey] >= elemb[mkey]:
                retval.append(elemA)
            else:  # Check mkey to see if take b instead
                retval.append(elemb)
            b_index = b_index + 1
        else:  # No match, check forward by one
            if b_index+1 >= len(b):
                continue
            elembplus = b[b_index+1]
            minb = { k: elembplus[k] for k in keys}
            if minA == minb:
                retval.append(elemb)  # This is a new element
                if elemA[mkey] >= elembplus[mkey]:
                    retval.append(elemA)
                else:
                    retval.append(elembplus)
                b_index = b_index + 2
    if b_index <= len(b):
        retval.extend(b[b_index:])
    return retval
```

This works fine as long as I don't get more than one additions and/or deletions (`b` relative to `A`) in a row. So if `A` contains 1, 2, 3, 5 and `b` contains 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 it's fine, but if `A` contains 1, 2, 5 and `b` contains 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 this breaks down.

I could do a check till len(b) under the else case commented as `# No match, check forward by one`, or first iterate through both `A` and `b` to map matching elements, then iterate through again based on that map to create retval. This seems error-prone though (I'm sure its do-able logic wise, but I'm also fairly sure code I write for it would be buggy). Please recommend a suitable algorithm to tackle this problem, whether it be my two ideas or something else.

Comment: You could hash your dict http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835668/python-dictionary-keyswhich-are-class-objects-comparison-with-multiple-compare and apply set operation over the list of hashed dict.

Comment: Thanks @AliSAIDOMAR but that doesn't answer my question on algorithm for priority-merge. Hashing is for making the comparison itself more efficient, and I'm not having issues with doing the comparisons themselves (see code example).

Answer (score 0):

As I told hash method could help you to ensure comparison, based only on `keys` list you will able to find the intersection element (element to merged) and difference element.

```
class HashedDictKey(dict):

    def __init__(self, keys_, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.keys_ = keys_

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(tuple(sorted((k, self.get(k)) for k in self.keys_)))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return  hash(self) == hash(other)

def merge(A, B):

    to_be_added = []
    to_be_del = []
    to_be_updated = []

    def get(obj, it):
        for i in it:
            if obj == i:
                return i
        raise ValueError("No %s value" % obj)

    for a, b in zip_longest(A, B):
        if a in B:
            to_be_updated.append(a)
        if a not in B:
            to_be_del.append(a)
        if b not in A:
            to_be_added.append(b)

    for i in to_be_del:
        A.remove(i)

    for j in to_be_added:
        A.append(j)

    for i in to_be_updated:
        a = get(i, A)
        b = get(i, B)
        if b['mtime'] > a['mtime']:
            A.remove(a)
```

[here the complete snippet](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fb9ede72b501788c759c80c77bbb5d02)